# Bar chart not starting at 0, with nodes in bars (in \subfloat)

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, pgfplotstable

I want to recreate the following Excel figure in to a larger figure in my style Latex:

[image]

For this to work, the figure needs to start at 0.6. When I do that (using ymin), the nodes drop down below the figure, which causes the subfloats below it to move down. I also want to:

- draw the orange and blue horizontal lines
- Draw the numbers and 'cleaning' nodes where they are in the excel figure

How do I add a line chart into the axis environment that specifices bar chart style? How do I add nodes to the figure? And the hardest I think: How do I get the nodes in bars to be where they are in the other latex figures?

Part of my LaTeX output so far:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[inner = 25mm, outer = 25mm,  top = 30mm, bottom = 20mm, headheight = 13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
    my third axis style/.style={
        width=\linewidth,
        height=0.35\linewidth,
        bar width=0.35, %<- changed
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.45},    % <-- changed to absolute coordinates
        ymin=0,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,1.15)},    % <-- adapted
            anchor=north,       % <-- changed from `north'
            legend columns=3,
        },
        ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A}},
        xtick=data,
        axis lines*=left,
        ymajorgrids,
        %
        table/x=x,
    },
    % created a style for the common `ybar' options
    my second ybar style/.style={
        ybar,
        my ybar legend,            % <-- change legend image accordingly
        #1!50!black,
        fill=black!20, line width = 1pt, %<- changed back
        nodes near coords,      % <-- moved from `axis' options here
        % state absolute positions for the `nodes near coords'
        scatter/position=absolute,
        node near coords style={
            % state where the nodes should appear
            at={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})},
            anchor=center,rotate=90, %<-added
            % make the font a bit smaller
            font=\footnotesize,
            % set the number format of the `nodes near coords'
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            precision=2,
            zerofill,
        },
    },
    my ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={
            \draw [
            ##1,
            /tikz/.cd,
            yshift=-0.25em,
            ] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);
        },
    },
}

\pgfplotstableread{%
    x   SP_CIGS_Left    SP_CIGS_Right   SP_cSi_left SP_cSi_right    WC_left WC_right    T4T_E   T4T_W   SP_CIGS_avg SP_cSi_avg  WC_avg  T4T_avg
    3   0.846   0.856   0.828   0.866   0.812   0.843   0.769   0.796   0.851   0.847   0.827   0.782
    4   0.847   0.857   0.834   0.870   0.810   0.845   0.806   0.815   0.852   0.852   0.827   0.811
    5   0.849   0.854   0.837   0.877   0.807   0.846   0.785   0.808   0.852   0.857   0.826   0.797
    6   0.839   0.850   0.844   0.876   0.809   0.846   0.807   0.817   0.844   0.860   0.827   0.812
    7   0.835   0.844   0.845   0.875   0.806   0.841   0.778   0.835   0.840   0.860   0.823   0.806
    8   0.842   0.849   0.845   0.873   0.801   0.841   0.801   0.807   0.846   0.859   0.821   0.804
    9   0.839   0.847   0.852   0.883   0.815   0.853   0.818   0.817   0.843   0.868   0.834   0.818
    10  0.763   0.749   0.870   0.878   0.879   0.893   0.866   0.882   0.756   0.874   0.886   0.874
    11  0.905   0.770   0.877   0.905   0.865   0.884   0.812   0.839   0.837   0.891   0.875   0.826
    12  0.924   0.798   0.895   0.912   0.861   0.889   0.809   0.851   0.861   0.903   0.875   0.830
    13  0.917   0.787   0.886   0.906   0.863   0.885   0.801   0.828   0.851   0.896   0.874   0.814
    14  0.914   0.787   0.869   0.899   0.854   0.879   0.794   0.808   0.850   0.884   0.866   0.801
    15  0.913   0.784   0.877   0.898   0.858   0.883   0.785   0.819   0.848   0.887   0.870   0.802
}{\loadedtablesoiling}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \subfloat[System 1]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my third axis style, legend style={at={(0.5,1.2)}}, ymin = 0.6, ybar, ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A,tc}}, xtick= data, xticklabels = {3-7,4-7,5-7,6-7,7-7,8-7,9-7,10-7,11-7,12-7,13-7,14-7,15-7}]
        \addplot [my second ybar style=red!50!black, fill = black!10] table [y=SP_CIGS_Left] {\loadedtablesoiling};
        \addplot [my second ybar style=red!50!black,] table [y=SP_CIGS_Right] {\loadedtablesoiling}; \ref{bars}
        \addlegendimage{my temp plot}
        \legend{PR\textsubscript{A,tc} per day, Temperature}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \subfloat[System 2]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my third axis style, ybar, ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A,tc}}, xtick= data, xticklabels = {3-7,4-7,5-7,6-7,7-7,8-7,9-7,10-7,11-7,12-7,13-7,14-7,15-7}]
        \addplot [my second ybar style=blue!50!black, fill = black!10] table [y=SP_cSi_left] {\loadedtablesoiling};
        \addplot [my second ybar style=blue!50!black,] table [y=SP_cSi_right] {\loadedtablesoiling}; 
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \subfloat[System 3]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my third axis style, ybar, ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A,tc}}, xtick= data, xticklabels = {3-7,4-7,5-7,6-7,7-7,8-7,9-7,10-7,11-7,12-7,13-7,14-7,15-7}]
        \addplot [my second ybar style=black, fill = black!10] table [y=T4T_E] {\loadedtablesoiling};
        \addplot [my second ybar style=black,] table [y=T4T_W] {\loadedtablesoiling}; 
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \subfloat[System 4]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my third axis style, ybar, ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A,tc}}, xtick=data, xticklabels = {3-7,4-7,5-7,6-7,7-7,8-7,9-7,10-7,11-7,12-7,13-7,14-7,15-7}, xlabel = Week number]
        \addplot [my second ybar style=green!50!black, fill = black!10] table [y=WC_left] {\loadedtablesoiling};
        \addplot [my second ybar style=green!50!black,] table [y=WC_right] {\loadedtablesoiling}; 
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \caption{PR\textsubscript{A,tc} before and after cleaning}
    \label{fig:soiling pr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Stop using absolute coordinates.  Use (axis cs: x,y) instead, or create named coordinates and use them.

Comment: What do you expect? You say explicitly `at={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})},`. Where should these nodes be? Above the bars or, which seems implicit in your plot, below the `x` axis?

Answer (score 1):

I would just adjust the `nodes near coords` to take into account `ymin`.

```
at={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},
            0.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}))},
            anchor=center,rotate=90, %<-added
```

That's the code then.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[inner = 25mm, outer = 25mm,  top = 30mm, bottom = 20mm, headheight = 13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
    my third axis style/.style={
        width=\linewidth,
        height=0.35\linewidth,
        bar width=0.35, %<- changed
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.45},    % <-- changed to absolute coordinates
        ymin=0,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,1.15)},    % <-- adapted
            anchor=north,       % <-- changed from `north'
            legend columns=3,
        },
        ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A}},
        xtick=data,
        axis lines*=left,
        ymajorgrids,
        %
        table/x=x,
    },
    % created a style for the common `ybar' options
    my second ybar style/.style={
        ybar,
        my ybar legend,            % <-- change legend image accordingly
        #1!50!black,
        fill=black!20, line width = 1pt, %<- changed back
        nodes near coords,      % <-- moved from `axis' options here
        % state absolute positions for the `nodes near coords'
        scatter/position=absolute,
        node near coords style={
            % state where the nodes should appear
            at={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},
            0.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}))},
            anchor=center,rotate=90, %<-added
            % make the font a bit smaller
            font=\footnotesize,
            % set the number format of the `nodes near coords'
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            precision=2,
            zerofill,
        },
    },
    my ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={
            \draw [
            ##1,
            /tikz/.cd,
            yshift=-0.25em,
            ] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);
        },
    },
}

\pgfplotstableread{%
    x   SP_CIGS_Left    SP_CIGS_Right   SP_cSi_left SP_cSi_right    WC_left WC_right    T4T_E   T4T_W   SP_CIGS_avg SP_cSi_avg  WC_avg  T4T_avg
    3   0.846   0.856   0.828   0.866   0.812   0.843   0.769   0.796   0.851   0.847   0.827   0.782
    4   0.847   0.857   0.834   0.870   0.810   0.845   0.806   0.815   0.852   0.852   0.827   0.811
    5   0.849   0.854   0.837   0.877   0.807   0.846   0.785   0.808   0.852   0.857   0.826   0.797
    6   0.839   0.850   0.844   0.876   0.809   0.846   0.807   0.817   0.844   0.860   0.827   0.812
    7   0.835   0.844   0.845   0.875   0.806   0.841   0.778   0.835   0.840   0.860   0.823   0.806
    8   0.842   0.849   0.845   0.873   0.801   0.841   0.801   0.807   0.846   0.859   0.821   0.804
    9   0.839   0.847   0.852   0.883   0.815   0.853   0.818   0.817   0.843   0.868   0.834   0.818
    10  0.763   0.749   0.870   0.878   0.879   0.893   0.866   0.882   0.756   0.874   0.886   0.874
    11  0.905   0.770   0.877   0.905   0.865   0.884   0.812   0.839   0.837   0.891   0.875   0.826
    12  0.924   0.798   0.895   0.912   0.861   0.889   0.809   0.851   0.861   0.903   0.875   0.830
    13  0.917   0.787   0.886   0.906   0.863   0.885   0.801   0.828   0.851   0.896   0.874   0.814
    14  0.914   0.787   0.869   0.899   0.854   0.879   0.794   0.808   0.850   0.884   0.866   0.801
    15  0.913   0.784   0.877   0.898   0.858   0.883   0.785   0.819   0.848   0.887   0.870   0.802
}{\loadedtablesoiling}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \subfloat[System 1]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my third axis style, legend style={at={(0.5,1.2)}},
         ymin = 0.6, ybar, ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A,tc}}, xtick= data, xticklabels = {3-7,4-7,5-7,6-7,7-7,8-7,9-7,10-7,11-7,12-7,13-7,14-7,15-7}]
        \addplot [my second ybar style=red!50!black, fill = black!10] table [y=SP_CIGS_Left] {\loadedtablesoiling};
        \addplot [my second ybar style=red!50!black,] table [y=SP_CIGS_Right] {\loadedtablesoiling}; \ref{bars}
        \addlegendimage{my temp plot}
        \legend{PR\textsubscript{A,tc} per day, Temperature}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \subfloat[System 2]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my third axis style, ybar, ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A,tc}}, xtick= data, xticklabels = {3-7,4-7,5-7,6-7,7-7,8-7,9-7,10-7,11-7,12-7,13-7,14-7,15-7}]
        \addplot [my second ybar style=blue!50!black, fill = black!10] table [y=SP_cSi_left] {\loadedtablesoiling};
        \addplot [my second ybar style=blue!50!black,] table [y=SP_cSi_right] {\loadedtablesoiling}; 
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \subfloat[System 3]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my third axis style, ybar, ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A,tc}}, xtick= data, xticklabels = {3-7,4-7,5-7,6-7,7-7,8-7,9-7,10-7,11-7,12-7,13-7,14-7,15-7}]
        \addplot [my second ybar style=black, fill = black!10] table [y=T4T_E] {\loadedtablesoiling};
        \addplot [my second ybar style=black,] table [y=T4T_W] {\loadedtablesoiling}; 
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \subfloat[System 4]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my third axis style, ybar, ylabel={PR\textsubscript{A,tc}}, xtick=data, xticklabels = {3-7,4-7,5-7,6-7,7-7,8-7,9-7,10-7,11-7,12-7,13-7,14-7,15-7}, xlabel = Week number]
        \addplot [my second ybar style=green!50!black, fill = black!10] table [y=WC_left] {\loadedtablesoiling};
        \addplot [my second ybar style=green!50!black,] table [y=WC_right] {\loadedtablesoiling}; 
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \caption{PR\textsubscript{A,tc} before and after cleaning}
    \label{fig:soiling pr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Do you also know how to add the lines and nodes?

Comment: @Hans Is there any systematics behind the bars? (You can always add draw commands.) What determines these values (I see of course that these are the heights of some bars, but why those?) P.S. I still could not solve the time parsing problem but I am learning new tricks. ;-)

Comment: The bars indicate performance ratios of a photovoltaic system. The lines indicate the average performance ratio for the days before and after cleaning. The calculation is done separately, so I only want to add the numbers manually. Thanks a lot for the help so far :)

Comment: @Hans You can simply add draw commands. Just add `\draw[orange,very thick] (3,0.87) -- (5.5,0.87) node[midway,above]{0.85};
  \draw[orange,very thick] (6,0.86) -- (9.5,0.86) node[midway,above]{0.84};` to the first plot to get a feeling.

Comment: thanks. Is there an overview of the options for this \draw[] command? The nodes overlap, so I want on to be just left of midway and on to be just right of midway. I also want to raise one to be at the same height as the other

Comment: @Hans `\draw` is one of the standard Ti*k*Z commands. It is discussed at length in the pgfmanual. `midway` is synonymous to `pos=0.5`. If you want to shift a bit to the left, you could use `pos=0.4`, say.